# checking String's First letter for Special case and check the String with Space?

Tags: c

I Wrote correct Code For 4 Test cases But struggling to write 2 test cases out of which one is a hidden test case(string with space)

In the gifts store, Tintu finds a lot of fancy articles with letters inscribed in it. She decides to select gifts for her friends such that the first letter of their names is inscribed in the gift articles.

There is a hifi-scanner device in the gifts shop that would illuminate the articles that contain the letters fed as input. There is another interfacing device that would pick the 1st letters of all names entered by the user. Suddenly the device started malfunctioning and Nisha the owner of the shop is very tensed. Tintu is a very close friend of Nisha and she offers to help her in fixing this issue. She starts rewriting the program to be embedded in the scanner like device. Can you help her out?

> TestCase
>
> Input 1
>
> MAHIRL
>
> CHITRA
>
> DEVI
>
> C
>
> Output 1
>
> yes
>
> Input 2
>
> MAHIRL
>
> CHITRA
>
> DEVI
>
> A
>
> Output 2
>
> no
>
> Input 3
>
> JON SNOW
>
> ARYA STARK
>
> HODOR
>
> S
>
> Output 3
>
> no
>
> Input 4
>
> @ON SNOW
>
> ARYA STARK
>
> HODOR
>
> @
>
> Output 4
>
> no

The program below satisfies four of the test cases but it fails on two of them (special character and string with space)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char a[256],b[256],c[256];
    char d[256];
    printf("Enter the first name");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("Enter the Second name");
    scanf("%s",&b);
    printf("Enter the third name");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    printf("Enter the first Letter");
    scanf("%s",&d);
    if(a[0] == "!@#$%^&*+<>?|.,/[{]}\`~*:;'-_=)(" || b[0] == "!@#$%^&*+<>?|.,/[{]}\`~*:;'-_=)(" || c[0] == "!@#$%^&*+<>?|.,/[{]}\`~*:;'-_=)(" || d[0] == "!@#$%^&*+<>?|.,/[{]}\`~*:;'-_=)(")
    printf("\nNo");
    if(d[0] == a[0] || d[0] == b[0] || d[0] == c[0])
    printf("\nYes");
    else
    printf("\nNo");
}
```

Comment: Compiling that program throws warnings like crazy, maybe you should take care of those too.

Comment: Not certain what that first `if` statement is trying to do, but it's not valid C and is never going to print "No"

Comment: @ChrisTurner I Tried that statement to check for Special cases.It didn't work.But it doesn't affect other test case's Output. They work fine.

Comment: `a[0] == "!@#$%^&*+<>?|.,/[{]}\`~*:;'-_=)("` is comparing a `char` to a string literal.  Code instead needs to compare against each `char` of the literal.  See `strchr()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it feels like an exam question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the code of @prudhviraj and I got the solution I need.

Thanks @prudhviraj!

```
void main()
{
    char a[256], b[256], c[256], d[256];

    fgets(a,256,stdin);
    fgets(b,256,stdin);
    fgets(c,256,stdin);
    fgets(d,256,stdin);

    if((a[0] < 'A' || a[0] > 'Z') || (b[0] < 'A' || b[0] > 'Z') || (c[0] < 'A' || c[0] > 'Z') || (d[0] < 'A' || d[0] > 'Z'))
        printf("\nno");
    else if(d[0]==a[0] || d[0]==b[0] || d[0]==c[0])
        printf("\nyes");
    else
        printf("\nno");
}
```

Comment: a[0] less than char A and a[0] > char z. same for all strings

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
       char a[256],b[256],c[256],d[256];

        fgets(a,256,stdin);
        fgets(b,256,stdin);
        fgets(c,256,stdin);
        fgets(d,256,stdin);
        if(d[0]==a[0]||d[0]==b[0]||d[0]==c[0])
        printf("\nyes");
        else
        printf("\nno");
    }

this will help you pass the string with space test case.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char a[50],b[50],c[50],ch[50];
    fgets(a,50,stdin);
    fgets(b,50,stdin);
    fgets(c,50,stdin);
    fgets(ch,50,stdin);
    if((a[0]>='A' && a[0]<='Z') && (b[0]>='A' && b[0]<='Z') && (c[0]>='A' && c[0]<='Z') && (ch[0]>='A' && ch[0]<='Z'))
    {
        if(a[0]==ch[0] || b[0]==ch[0] ||c[0]==ch[0])
        {
            printf("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no");
    }
}
```

This code evaluates all the 6 cases including special character case and blank space case.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char a[100],b[100],c[100],d[100];
gets(a);
gets(b);
gets(c);
gets(d);
if(d[0]>=0 && d[0]<=64)
printf("no");
else if(a[0]==d[0] || b[0]==d[0] || c[0]==d[0])
printf("yes");
else
printf("no");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.